# How to return a list of all URL's in a YouTube playlist using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, youtube, playlist

[image]I've tried many methods from similar questions and can't get anything to return the video URL's.
Using Chrome DevTools, the a links with hrefs for video urls are clearly in there, but when I try to return anything with an href in the format of a video url, nothing appears.

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

def getlinks(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, features='lxml')
    for link in soup.find_all("a"):
        href = link.get('href')
        if href.startswith('/watch?'):
            print(href)

getlinks('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev')
```

Comment: YouTube is dynamically loaded using `javascript`. Try using `selenium`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube is dynamically loaded using `javascript`. The best way to scrape dynamic websites is to use `selenium`. Here is the full code to do it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def getlinks(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(4)
    soup = bs(driver.page_source, features='lxml')
    for link in soup.find_all("a"):
        try:
            href = link.get('href')
            if href.startswith('/watch?'):
                print(href)
        except:
            pass 

    driver.close()

getlinks('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev')
```

Output:

```
/watch?v=QktCIWrt04Q&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev
/watch?v=QktCIWrt04Q&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev
/watch?v=1PT7MP5VxDA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev
/watch?v=QktCIWrt04Q&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=1
/watch?v=QktCIWrt04Q&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=1
/watch?v=d55aj7CPRUU&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=2
/watch?v=d55aj7CPRUU&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=2
/watch?v=V0_WnzO1hdE&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=3
/watch?v=V0_WnzO1hdE&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=3
/watch?v=y8byHSLhbcA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=4
/watch?v=y8byHSLhbcA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=4
/watch?v=0BKEYKDG5x0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=5
/watch?v=0BKEYKDG5x0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=5
/watch?v=fFB4xcH7Xik&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=6
/watch?v=fFB4xcH7Xik&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=6
/watch?v=0Y3Ln0qB7NE&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=7
/watch?v=0Y3Ln0qB7NE&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=7
/watch?v=63SP6JI4bNU&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=8
/watch?v=63SP6JI4bNU&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=8
/watch?v=eApXnJUczCI&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=9
/watch?v=eApXnJUczCI&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=9
/watch?v=0nWePxShMqk&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=10
/watch?v=0nWePxShMqk&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=10
/watch?v=z9EcZkTTMVY&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=11
/watch?v=z9EcZkTTMVY&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=11
/watch?v=ZpJIDYphWTI&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=12
/watch?v=ZpJIDYphWTI&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=12
/watch?v=FI2XIYadz1c&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=13
/watch?v=FI2XIYadz1c&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=13
/watch?v=fc4kvEElN7c&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=14
/watch?v=fc4kvEElN7c&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=14
/watch?v=6MN6Z0XBqLA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=15
/watch?v=6MN6Z0XBqLA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=15
/watch?v=RgWxEtOE3sU&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=16
/watch?v=RgWxEtOE3sU&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=16
/watch?v=t9U7t1NoXiw&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=17
/watch?v=t9U7t1NoXiw&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=17
/watch?v=m420JGn9yyk&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=18
/watch?v=m420JGn9yyk&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=18
/watch?v=p-Cr8Y8ZTz0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=19
/watch?v=p-Cr8Y8ZTz0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=19
/watch?v=g2t2qjOh-AE&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=20
/watch?v=g2t2qjOh-AE&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=20
/watch?v=qSkWUONMJSY&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=21
/watch?v=qSkWUONMJSY&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=21
/watch?v=FYMy8HaWrX4&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=22
/watch?v=FYMy8HaWrX4&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=22
/watch?v=nk5V0VbLkrI&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=23
/watch?v=nk5V0VbLkrI&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=23
/watch?v=HAsjI7wyDBg&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=24
/watch?v=HAsjI7wyDBg&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=24
/watch?v=eUKNj9VrJIU&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=25
/watch?v=eUKNj9VrJIU&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=25
/watch?v=e8Fjy01Acl0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=26
/watch?v=e8Fjy01Acl0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=26
/watch?v=ntz-mYI-ZBU&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=27
/watch?v=ntz-mYI-ZBU&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=27
/watch?v=kCnuXGzRO2Q&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=28
/watch?v=kCnuXGzRO2Q&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=28
/watch?v=YZWVAG7PMbo&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=29
/watch?v=YZWVAG7PMbo&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=29
/watch?v=xFIjEGwVTrI&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=30
/watch?v=xFIjEGwVTrI&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=30
/watch?v=BP9W16ay_vU&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=31
/watch?v=BP9W16ay_vU&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=31
/watch?v=tiTuSBs5k4k&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=32
/watch?v=tiTuSBs5k4k&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=32
/watch?v=_cU0eSNx1xk&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=33
/watch?v=_cU0eSNx1xk&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=33
/watch?v=xv6s5LYh5kA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=34
/watch?v=xv6s5LYh5kA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=34
/watch?v=0SQWvDK9_c8&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=35
/watch?v=0SQWvDK9_c8&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=35
/watch?v=1PT7MP5VxDA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=36
/watch?v=1PT7MP5VxDA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=36
/watch?v=1U_m3UNm93I&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=37
/watch?v=1U_m3UNm93I&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=37
/watch?v=eZlXaNaLfa8&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=38
/watch?v=eZlXaNaLfa8&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=38
/watch?v=cohVBrS9sss&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=39
/watch?v=cohVBrS9sss&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=39
/watch?v=Ulb3esvyy0I&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=40
/watch?v=Ulb3esvyy0I&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=40
/watch?v=BRiTeq0sWVo&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=41
/watch?v=BRiTeq0sWVo&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=41
/watch?v=clexityYu5k&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=42
/watch?v=clexityYu5k&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=42
/watch?v=DXGbsaU5FU0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=43
/watch?v=DXGbsaU5FU0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=43
/watch?v=JMl6K4-1BI0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=44
/watch?v=JMl6K4-1BI0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=44
/watch?v=Bry5nbhl-60&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=45
/watch?v=Bry5nbhl-60&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=45
/watch?v=KPHivuf5eqo&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=46
/watch?v=KPHivuf5eqo&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=46
/watch?v=H08DcY1tsUI&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=47
/watch?v=H08DcY1tsUI&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=47
/watch?v=19d7Ir3LGik&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=48
/watch?v=19d7Ir3LGik&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=48
/watch?v=DgDCjLd3tP4&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=49
/watch?v=DgDCjLd3tP4&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=49
/watch?v=JmjDu0Qx2GA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=50
/watch?v=JmjDu0Qx2GA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=50
/watch?v=Dw8kqBbRJPI&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=51
/watch?v=Dw8kqBbRJPI&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=51
/watch?v=i7DdXfbZhmQ&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=52
/watch?v=i7DdXfbZhmQ&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=52
/watch?v=O5KUFnthO4w&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=53
/watch?v=O5KUFnthO4w&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=53
/watch?v=HdrQ8qxJ8m0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=54
/watch?v=HdrQ8qxJ8m0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=54
/watch?v=8U9pwWqAKCE&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=55
/watch?v=8U9pwWqAKCE&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=55
/watch?v=orakWbfY86k&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=56
/watch?v=orakWbfY86k&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=56
/watch?v=J-YN9L3gvmQ&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=57
/watch?v=J-YN9L3gvmQ&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=57
/watch?v=GzzN_z_exSw&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=58
/watch?v=GzzN_z_exSw&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=58
/watch?v=CnJWxnXY7Tg&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=59
/watch?v=CnJWxnXY7Tg&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=59
/watch?v=UXteHWBdQfo&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=60
/watch?v=UXteHWBdQfo&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=60
/watch?v=OSrI0btxn_g&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=61
/watch?v=OSrI0btxn_g&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=61
/watch?v=w1YcbkJZ2aQ&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=62
/watch?v=w1YcbkJZ2aQ&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=62
/watch?v=lkisdRsjIF0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=63
/watch?v=lkisdRsjIF0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=63
/watch?v=zCjW5lvlLBc&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=64
/watch?v=zCjW5lvlLBc&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=64
/watch?v=pwLoCEzytyI&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=65
/watch?v=pwLoCEzytyI&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=65
/watch?v=K1mxzhZZZzA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=66
/watch?v=K1mxzhZZZzA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=66
/watch?v=zfAkzOEvYys&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=67
/watch?v=zfAkzOEvYys&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=67
/watch?v=yjoMEvS7vgg&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=68
/watch?v=yjoMEvS7vgg&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=68
/watch?v=fXB7p01YKxg&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=69
/watch?v=fXB7p01YKxg&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=69
/watch?v=vDr1z1Idbi8&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=70
/watch?v=vDr1z1Idbi8&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=70
/watch?v=VPwmYGteKBA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=71
/watch?v=VPwmYGteKBA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=71
/watch?v=nRlMGZUd5vc&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=72
/watch?v=nRlMGZUd5vc&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=72
/watch?v=97X2vjiLh8s&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=73
/watch?v=97X2vjiLh8s&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=73
/watch?v=qBW68T_PYDg&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=74
/watch?v=qBW68T_PYDg&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=74
/watch?v=xvrmcPnNQAg&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=75
/watch?v=xvrmcPnNQAg&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=75
/watch?v=RCm5pxLxTnE&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=76
/watch?v=RCm5pxLxTnE&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=76
/watch?v=hHBnPey8CCQ&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=77
/watch?v=hHBnPey8CCQ&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=77
/watch?v=ZsTy9pSLXNw&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=78
/watch?v=ZsTy9pSLXNw&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=78
/watch?v=jzKLVnDTSrs&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=79
/watch?v=jzKLVnDTSrs&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=79
/watch?v=NLoYKYudBk4&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=80
/watch?v=NLoYKYudBk4&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=80
/watch?v=HzLDetYIxTg&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=81
/watch?v=HzLDetYIxTg&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=81
/watch?v=86qvqJsd97Y&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=82
/watch?v=86qvqJsd97Y&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=82
/watch?v=cwen9S-Ckuo&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=83
/watch?v=cwen9S-Ckuo&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=83
/watch?v=2kdvdoWaoSU&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=84
/watch?v=2kdvdoWaoSU&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=84
/watch?v=VCUF0Xtop8o&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=85
/watch?v=VCUF0Xtop8o&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=85
/watch?v=tKGL4N87PMU&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=86
/watch?v=tKGL4N87PMU&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=86
/watch?v=GR_jRvqQ9Lo&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=87
/watch?v=GR_jRvqQ9Lo&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=87
/watch?v=0wEOCpLCabo&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=88
/watch?v=0wEOCpLCabo&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=88
/watch?v=Fvs5ytXZ7Cw&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=89
/watch?v=Fvs5ytXZ7Cw&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=89
/watch?v=weuz6Imoll0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=90
/watch?v=weuz6Imoll0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=90
/watch?v=8NEJwtWjppY&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=91
/watch?v=8NEJwtWjppY&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=91
/watch?v=7J0o12rE9FA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=92
/watch?v=7J0o12rE9FA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=92
/watch?v=QujbxxETYaI&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=93
/watch?v=QujbxxETYaI&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=93
/watch?v=RSRh3NtDjbc&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=94
/watch?v=RSRh3NtDjbc&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=94
/watch?v=ERQNhqghg5E&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=95
/watch?v=ERQNhqghg5E&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=95
/watch?v=Edguhs6NtM0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=96
/watch?v=Edguhs6NtM0&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=96
/watch?v=KIPZ9EJ2LaM&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=97
/watch?v=KIPZ9EJ2LaM&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=97
/watch?v=8eLYQeB5UEk&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=98
/watch?v=8eLYQeB5UEk&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=98
/watch?v=HOzTLDzlHjk&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=99
/watch?v=HOzTLDzlHjk&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=99
/watch?v=zMqS1hzCUuA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=100
/watch?v=zMqS1hzCUuA&list=PLU6BYY1Lu_feVbuZEscpd6xT32zCrVrev&index=100
```